# How to remove blank data in column chart in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, column-chart

I have used the following dax formula to count rows based on dates filtering out blank ("null") data:

`Avsluttet = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(TICKET),NOT(ISBLANK('Table'[closed_at])), USERELATIONSHIP(Dato[Opprettet dato], TICKET[closed_at]))`

In the visualization one column is appearing blank, why is that when I have excluded blank data in the measure?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Avsluttet = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(TICKET),'Table'[closed_at] <> BLANK(), USERELATIONSHIP(Dato[Opprettet dato], TICKET[closed_at]))
```

You can read why here: https://dax.guide/isblank/

Empty strings are not considered blank by ISBLANK() (strict equality is used).

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting the same result.

Comment: Can you share a .pbix? Are you using a star schema? What is the value contained in your blank?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't share a p.bix since it is work related. Yes, in this case column 'Dato [Opprettet dato]' is connected to 'TICKET[closed_at]' as a dimension table. 'TICKET' is the fact table. When I filter 'closed_at' column only dates and "(null)" data appears, however column statistics tells me that I have 4 empty cells. I'm trying to locate them, but not sure how.

Comment: If it is a dimension table, you may have dates in your fact table which are not present in your date dimension and thus represented as blank.